# Log det of covariance and entropy

Tags: statistics, information-theory, covariance, entropy, upper-lower-bounds

I understand log of determinant of covariance matrix bounds entropy for gaussian distributed data. Is this the case for non gaussian data as well and if so, why?

[What does Determinant of Covariance Matrix give?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889425/what-does-determinant-of-covariance-matrix-give) and http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~phwang/teaching/2012s/IT/slides/chap08.pdf show connection between 'differential entropy' and log of determinant of covariance matrix for Gaussian case. Eqn. 26 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03924.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1tDOzgZ2iXSo3lDbXnr8TUkxawCA8NikHFlfY4E5OWmbmJ3_WHeVPotFE has some relations (I guess for non-Gaussian case, but yet to check that)

Comment: For context, please mention some of the bounds (names/statements) of the bounds that you have seen. This will help  others attract your attention towards similar bounds for possibly non-Gaussian data.

Comment: added the links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand log of determinant of covariance matrix bounds entropy for gaussian distributed data

Wrong. That's not a bound, it's the value of entropy for a gaussian. And it's not exactly 
log of determinant of covariance matrix [but](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029707/entropy-of-the-multivariate-gaussian)

$$H(Z)=\frac{k}{2} \ln(2 \pi e)+\frac12 \ln (| \Sigma|)$$

> Is this the case for non gaussian data as well and if so, why?

It's a well known result that the gaussian distribution maximizes the entropy, for a given covariance. See eg [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194051/prove-that-the-maximum-entropy-distribution-with-a-fixed-covariance-matrix-is-a).

Hence, yes, that value is a bound.

Comment: What does 'previous value' refer to in your answer? For the non gaussian case it being a bound , is what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, I meant the value of the equation above.

Comment: is there a similar bound or any bound for that sake on cross-entropy based on determinants?